# Compare only last segment of each string an array of strings with Measure-Object, and return the whole string

Tags: powershell

I and trying to find the folder among subfolders withing a list of folders, which has the oldest date in it's name, and return the whole path.

This is what I had so far...

```
$folders= @()
Get-Content -Path .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object{
echo "path is $_"
$oldest = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum)
echo "oldest folder is $($oldest.Minimum)"
$folders += "$_\$($oldest.Minimum)"
}
$minMin =($folders | Measure-Object -Minimum)
echo $minMin.Minimum
```

This returns:

```
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1
oldest folder is 2019-12-18
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\2
oldest folder is 2019-12-18
path is C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\3
oldest folder is 2019-12-10
C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1\2019-12-18
```

For each string in the array, this is comparing the whole string  e.g.`C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1\2019-12-18`
I'd like to only compare the date at the end, but then return the whole string.

So if `$folders` contains:

```
C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\1\2019-12-18
C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\2\2019-12-18
C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\3\2019-12-10
```

I want it to return `C:\Local Files\Script testing\Dates\3\2019-12-10`

I can't think how to do this. I can split it, and compare the last folder name, but then I don't know how I'd match it up with the original folder it came from. I also don't know how I'd handle duplicates. In the end the folder structure will be like

```
D:\server1_data\2020-01-24
D:\server2_data\2020-01-24
...
```

Falling back to the `serverX_data` to solve the duplicate, or just an arbitrary single result would be ok as well. Again I can't think how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep track of the full path to each folder but still be able to get the lowest date, I would recommend using a dictionary / hashtable.

Also, you dont have to use, `echo` to display any value. For powershell, I would really recommend using Write-Output or Write-Host. Simply writing text would also print it to console without the use of echo, write-host etc.

```
$folders = @{} # Hashtable

Get-Content -Path .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Output "path is $_"
  $oldest = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum)
  Write-Output "oldest folder is $($oldest.Minimum)"

  $folders[$oldest.Minimum] += "$_\$($oldest.Minimum);" #Multiple values each ending with ; 
}

$minMin = $folders.Keys | Measure-Object -Minimum
$minMin.Minimum

# Get All paths for minimum Date
$folders[$minMin.Minimum]
```

**$Folders data will be like this**

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2019-12-10                     C:\Temp\Dates\1\2019-12-10;                                                                                                                                                                                           
2019-12-18                     C:\Temp\Dates\2\2019-12-18;C:\Temp\Dates\3\2019-12-18;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did just figure out a working solution. It feels like a kludge, but it works. I will look at yours for sure though.

Comment: This is the answer, I just had to add `$folders = $folders[$minMin.Minimum].Split(";")`, and `$folders[0]` at the end. To get a single folder, in the case of multiples.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it work in this way, but it feels like a kludge, will try the solution from Jawad.

```
$folders= @()
$subFolders= @()
$count=0
Get-Content -Path .\folders.txt | ForEach-Object{
echo "path is $_"
$oldest = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$_" -Name | Measure-Object -Minimum)
echo "oldest folder is $($oldest.Minimum)"
$folders += "$_\$($oldest.Minimum)"
$subFolders += "$($oldest.Minimum)"
$count += 1
}
echo $oldest.Minimum
$minMin=($subFolders | Measure-Object -Minimum)
$foldersIndex = $subFolders.IndexOf($($minMin.Minimum))
$folders[$foldersIndex]
```